# heightForWidth label

Tags: qt, pyqt

4-5 years I needed a widget with the following properties

- Display text incl. HTML
- Text should be wrapped on several lines
- When the widget is put into a layout, the height of the widget should be adjusted in such a way that the text exactly fits the widget geometry

This subwidget should be used in a layout to provide some detail on how the other GUI elements in the layout work but only consume a minimum space to display its content.

I thought this was an easy one - but each time I return to the challenge I always end by giving up.

The main problem is that the layout breaks down when heightForWidth() is implemented and a QSizePolicy with setHeightForWidth(True) is used. It can shrink to infinitely small. Apparently this is Qt bug.

Another approach is to call updateGeometry() when a resizeEvent() occurs and call setFixedHeight(h) using a width dependent height. But this also gives rise to some weird layout behavior.

If anybody has any good suggestions on how to approach this, please let me know.

Below I include a snippet that reproduces the layout resizing behavior.

Best regards,

Mads

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Square(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor('red'))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        policy = self.sizePolicy()
        policy.setHeightForWidth(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(policy)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(128, 128)

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        return width

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Call base class constructor
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Add a layout
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Add Square
        label = Square()
        layout.addWidget(label)

        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        layout.addItem(spacerItem)

        # Some dummy button
        self._push_button = QtGui.QPushButton('Press me')
        layout.addWidget(self._push_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The qlabel wordwrap is notoriously buggy sadly. With all the potential inter-text html styling, fonts and breaks, it's apparently a very hard problem to solve

Comment: Yeah, I suspected something along these lines. Too bad, the feature seems to be something of a generic interest.

Answer (score 8):

I found this extremely problematic. I think the core of the problem is as follows:

- Qt layouts are typically assigned to a widget that we can call the parent widget (with `parentwidget->setLayout(layout)`).
- Layouts ask their child widgets (or child layouts) for their size preferences (minimum size, size hint [preferred size], and maximum size). This is done in a slightly complex way via a `QLayoutItem`-derived class (e.g. `QWidgetItem`).
- Height-for-width (HFW) widgets -- those having `hasHeightForWidth() == true` and providing `int heightForWidth(int width)` -- have limited ability to describe their constraints to layouts, in that they can offer a `minimumSizeHint()`, a `sizeHint()`, and a `heightForWidth(width)`. They can, if necessary, also call functions like `setMinimumSize()` and `setMaximumSize()`. But most Qt layouts, like `QVBoxLayout`, `QHBoxLayout`, and `QGridLayout`, don't pay particular attention to the `heightForWidth(width)` results when offering their own min/preferred/max size to their parent, because they do so via `QLayout::minimumSize()`, `QLayout::sizeHint()`, and `QLayout::maximumSize()` -- none of which are called with information about the layout's target size (in a Catch-22-like situation), so they can't easily provide the `width` value to their children.
- So, the layout asks its children how big they want to be without much HFW thought, and thus sets its own minimum/preferred/maximum size (determining, potentially in conjunction with other constraints, the size of the parent widget).
- After the layout has told its parent (and its parent, etc.) how much space it needs, Qt works out how big it thinks everything should be. The layout is called via its `setGeometry(const QRect& layout_rect)`. Now the layout knows how big it is. It assigns space to its children with `child->setGeometry()`.
- But **only at this point** has the layout discovered its final width. So up to this point, it cannot offer a final width to its children, and thus HFW widgets can't know their final width until they're being laid out finally. By this time, the layout and its parent may already have been set to the wrong height (can be too big; can be too small).
- An excellent description of the widget/layout interaction is at http://kdemonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/understanding-qwidget-layout-flow.html; beyond this, you're best off looking at the Qt source code itself.

So you see two categories of solution, as you've outlined above, where size needs to be "properly" constrained to that required.

The first:

- HFW widgets, like `QLabel`-derived classes using word wrap, or images wanting to fix their aspect ratio, can provide sensible values for their minimum and maximum size, and a sensible `sizeHint()` (being the size they'd *like* to be).
- Then, when they're laid out, they (1) intercept `QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)` to find out their new width (e.g. from `event->size()`); (2) calculate their preferred height via their own `heightForWidth()` function; and (3) force their height via, for example, `setFixedHeight(height)` followed by `updateGeometry()`.
- This tends to work reasonably, *except* that any parent widget that wants to match its size to such an HFW widget has to do the same thing, e.g. intercepting `resizeEvent`, and if the parent widget has a layout with `hasHeightForWidth() == true`, doing something like `setFixedHeight(layout->heightForWidth(width())); updateGeometry();`.
- That leads to faff as you have to modify potentially arbitrary widgets in a long line of parenthood.
- It can also lead to quite a lot of redrawing, which can be slow and cause visual flickering.

The second:

- Rewrite the layouts.
- The best approach I've found is to have layouts calculate their children's geometry assuming some sort of standard rectangle (Qt itself often starts with a 640x480 one when drafting a layout); offering height information based on this draft; then, when setGeometry() is called, if the resulting height (based on a potentially new width) doesn't match what the layout previously advertised, re-constraining by calling `parent->setFixedHeight()`.
- This allows you to use arbitrary widgets, and HFW widgets only need to support `hasHeightForWidth()` and `heightForWidth()` to have the new layouts (and their parent widgets, and any ancestor layouts using this mechanism) adjust their height.
- It can lead to some redrawing, but often not too much, as it happens on a per-layout not per-widget basis.

I've put C++ code at http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/code/2017_01_16_qt_height_for_width/ for the following layouts:

- `BoxLayoutHfw`, `VBoxLayoutHfw`, `HBoxLayoutHfw` -- replacements for `QBoxLayout` etc.
- `GridLayoutHfw` -- replacements for `QGridLayout`.
- `FlowLayoutHfw` -- replacement for Qt's `FlowLayout` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).

and the following widgets:

- `AspectRatioPixmapLabel` -- image maintaining its aspect ratio;
- `LabelWordWrapWide` -- word-wrapping label that tries to use as much horizontal space before it word-wraps.
- `VerticalScrollArea` -- as its name suggests, a vertical scroll area, but one that supports height-for-width cleanly.

... plus some infrastructure code (`#define`s etc.) that should make the layouts revert to their Qt equivalent's behaviour, and some support files (including `gui_defines.h` and `layouts.h` that make the choice of layout and base widget conditional on your preference in this regard).

One residual problem that I've not successfully addressed is that I think `QLabel`'s `heightForWidth()` seems to return slightly wrong values (slightly overestimating its space requirements) with stylesheets under some circumstances. I suspect the problem is in `QLabelPrivate::sizeForWidth` but I've just worked around it imperfectly by calculating some stylesheet borders; it's still not quite right, but overestimating (leading to whitespace) is better than underestimating (leading to clipping).

Comment: That layout link is dead but the layouts can be found here https://github.com/ucam-department-of-psychiatry/camcops/blob/master/tablet_qt/layouts/

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for broken link; that's absolutely right, and original standalone version is now at https://rcardinal.ddns.net/code/2017_01_16_qt_height_for_width/ .

Answer (score 0):

Size hint will not dictate child widget's size except Fixed policy. If autoresize-like policies will surplus by parent.